# customer button ckeditor Cannot set property 'name' of undefined

Tags: javascript, ckeditor

It's my first time using ckeditor and i'm trying to do a custom-button.

In my plugin.js:

```
CKEDITOR.plugins.add('save-post',
{
    init: function (editor) {
    var pluginName = "save-post";
    //CKEDITOR.dialog.add(pluginName, this.path + 'dialogs/save-post.js');
    editor.addCommand(pluginName, SaveBlogPost());
    editor.ui.addButton('save-post',
    {
        label: 'save-post',
        command: pluginName
    });
  }
});
```

And here is another js-file:

```
function SaveBlogPost() {
    console.log("SAVEBLOGPOST");
 };
```

The console write out "SAVEBLOGPOST" when it creates the instance of the editor.
But after that i get "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property 'name' of undefined"

Where is this name it refers to?

Answer (score 0):

The "addCommand" method needs a command definition as second parameter.
You can find the doc and working example here: http://docs.ckeditor.com/#!/api/CKEDITOR.editor-method-addCommand